# -qmp option sends SIGINT to qemu

Tags: qemu, sigint

I use following script to start qemu with qmp

```
qmu-system-x86_64\
    -nographic \
    --enable-kvm \
    ...
    -qmp tcp:127.0.0.1:5555,server,nowait
```

When I hit CTRL-C inside the guest OS, I want my running process to be stopped without terminating the OS itself.

However, qmp option terminates my entire qemu when I hit CTRL-C with following message.

```
qemu-system-x86_64: terminating on signal 2
```

Without `qmp` option, it works as I desired.(kill process running inside guest OS, without killing guest itself).

Is there any way to use qmp option without killing qemu with CTRL-C?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to use qmp option without killing qemu with CTRL-C?

Adding `-serial mon:stdio` to your command line should help.